# Exchangeability of a Joint PDF

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm wondering why the exchangeability of the bivariate normal pdf, allows me to immediately write down the distribution of Y2, having found that of Y1.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to use "exchangeability" with a nonstandard meaning. Please specify this meaning.

Comment: Aplogies, I meant we can exchange y1 for y2, mu1 for mu2 and stdev1 for stdev2 and still be left with the same joint PDF.

Comment: This is **symmetry**, not exchangeability. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the joint density as
$$
f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=g(z_1;z_2;\rho),\qquad z_k=(y_k,\mu_k,\sigma_k^2),
$$
for some function $g$ symmetric with respect to $(z_1,z_2)$, that is, such that, for every $(z_1,z_2)$,
$$
g(z_1;z_2;\rho)=g(z_2;z_1;\rho).
$$
Then, $f_{Y_1}(y_1)=h(z_1)$ where $z_1=(y_1,\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$, the function $h$ does not depend on $(y_2,\mu_2,\sigma_2^2,\rho)$ and
$$
h(z_1)=\int g(z_1;y_2,\mu_2,\sigma_2^2;\rho)\,\mathrm dy_2.
$$
(The fact that $h$ does not depend on $\rho$ can be seen on the expression of $f_{Y_1}$ but it is not crucial to the argument below.) Likewise, by definition,
$$
f_{Y_2}(y_2)=\int f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)\,\mathrm dy_1,
$$
hence
$$
f_{Y_2}(y_2)=\int g(z_1;z_2;\rho)\,\mathrm dy_1=\int g(z_2;z_1;\rho)\,\mathrm dy_1=\int g(z_2;y_1,\mu_1,\sigma_1^2;\rho)\,\mathrm dy_1=h(z_2),
$$
where the first identity comes from the definition of $f_{Y_2}$ as the second marginal of  $f_{Y_1,Y_2}$ and the definition of $g$, the second identity comes from the symmetry of $g$, the third identity comes from the definition of $z_1$, and the fourth identity comes from the definition of $h$. To sum up, if
$$
f_{Y_1}(y_1)=h(y_1,\mu_1,\sigma_1^2),
$$
then
$$
f_{Y_2}(y_2)=h(y_2,\mu_2,\sigma_2^2),
$$
which is the symmetry you noticed.